# Matplotlib: how to scale the y axis according to the y-value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this figure plotted 4 bins together. Bins 1 to 4 contain, respectively 3, 29, 129 & 880 features. But unfortunately the first bin is almost not visible due to its small value. Is there a way to scale the y-axis so that all the bins are visible?

[image]

The code of cause:

```
#bins_label = [10,20,40,180]
bins = [bin10, bin20, bin40, bin180]
num_bins = 4
index = np.arange(num_bins)
plt.bar(index, bins,alpha=0.9, width=0.35, facecolor='lightskyblue', edgecolor='white', lw=1)
plt.xticks(index + 0.35, ('<10', '<20', '<40', '<180'))
plt.tight_layout();
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, you could use a log scale

Comment: Have you considered using a log scale ?

Comment: thanks! Now it looks fine. I just don't have intrinsic understanding of log so sometimes I don't know when to use the log scale